# How to simplify after quotient rule with positive and negative half exponents?

Tags: calculus

I can't figure out how the simplification is supposed to work:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\right)$$
$${dy\over dx} = {{(4-x^2)^{1\over 2}{d \over dx}(x^2)-x^2{d\over dx}(4-x^2)^{1\over 2}}\over{4-x^2}}$$
$$= {{(4-x^2)^{1\over 2}(2x)-x^2{1\over 2}(4-x^2)^{-1\over 2}(-2x)}\over{4-x^2}}$$
$$= {{(4-x^2)^{1\over 2}(2x)+x^3(4-x^2)^{-1\over 2}}\over{4-x^2}}\cdot {{(4-x^2)^{1\over 2}}\over{(4-x^2)^{1\over 2}}}$$
$$= {{(2x)(4-x^2)+x^3}\over{(4-x^2)^{3\over 2}}}$$
$$= {{8x-x^3}\over{(4-x^2)^{3\over 2}}}$$

It can't simplify through common terms, because the exponents are positive on one side and negative on the other. How does it work?

Comment: [This](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/quotientruledirectory/QuotientRule.html) has similar examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "on one side and the other".  What "sides" are you referring to?

In any case, can I assume that you know that the derivative of $\sqrt{4- x^2}= (4- x^2)^{1/2}$ is $(1/2)(4- x^2)^{-1/2}(-2x)= -\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4- x^2}}$?

If so then differentiating the fraction is just a matter of using the **quotient rule**: $$\left(\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}\right)'= \frac{u'(x)v(x)- u(x)v'(x)}{v^2(x)}$$ 
Here, $u(x)= x^2$ so $u'(x)= 2x$ and $v(x)=\sqrt{4- x^2}$ so, as above $v'(x)= -\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4- x^2}}$. 
\begin{align*} 
u'(x)v(x)- u(x)v'(x) & = -2x\sqrt{4- x^2}- x^2\left(-\frac{x}{\sqrt{4- x^2}}\right)\\
& = \frac{-2x(4- x^2)}{\sqrt{4- x^2}}+ \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{4- x^2}}\\
& = \frac{-8x+ 2x^3+ x^3}{\sqrt{4- x^2}}\\
& = 4\frac{x^3- 2x}{\sqrt{4- x^2}}
\end{align*}
Of course, $v^2(x)= \left(\sqrt{4- x^2}\right)^2= 4- x^2$ so the derivative is $4\frac{x^3- 2x}{(4- x^2)\sqrt{4- x^2}}$.

You might find it easier to write the original function as $x^2(4- x^2)^{1/2}$ and use the **product rule**, $(uv)'= u'v+ uv'$.  Again, $u(x)= x^2$ so $u'(x)= 2x$ but now $v(x)=(4- x^2)^{-1/2}$ so $$v'(x)= -\frac{1}{2}(4- x^2)^{-3/2}(-2x)= x(4- x^2)^{-3/2}$$  Then $$u'(x)v(x)+ u(x)v'(x)= 2x(4- x^2)^{-1/2}+ x^3(4- x^2)^{-3/2}$$  We can write $2x(4- x^2)^{-1/2}= 2x(4- x^2)(4- x^2)^{-3/2}$ and get the same derivative as before.

Comment: I fixed the typesetting errors, so you should be able to correct the final step in your quotient rule calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in the leftmost step of the bottom line of the solution, the answer-er multiplies the numerator and the denominator by $(4-x^2)^{1/2}$. This distributes to both terms in the numerator. In the term that already has $(4-x^2)^{1/2}$ in it, the product is $4-x^2$. In the term that has $(4-x^2)^{-1/2}$, the product is exactly 1. So in the end, there are no more square roots in the numerator. This is a very common technique for simplifying in quotient rule problems such as this one.

Comment: Where does the (4-x^2)^1/2 come from? Why was that chosen as something to multiple the denom and num by?

Comment: Is this because the exponent of -1/2 multiplies with 1/2 to make -1? Is it a rule that anything^-1 is automatically 1?

Comment: It was chosen because it makes the problem simpler. Actually, $(4-x^2)^{-1/2}\times(4-x^2)^{1/2}=(4-x^2)^0.$ The rule is that any number to the power of zero is one. Another way to see this is that $(4-x^2)^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{(4-x^2)^{1/2}}$.